# search for files with specific text and copy these files to another directory

Tags: files, search

How do I search for files in a directory that contain a specific text and copy them to another directory ? I am using .ksh shell.

Comment: Are you talking about text within the files?

Comment: Well, thinking about this, it would be kind of a lengthy command, and you would be better off making a script specifically for this.

Comment: Are all these files in the same directory or do you have to search recursively ? If it's the latter, then is the destination directory under the same directory you are searching in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do from the base directory you want to search

```
cp $(grep -r -l "the pattern" *) target_directory
```

- `grep -r` means recusive
- `-l` means list the file path not the match in it.
- putting `$()` around the command will execute it and place the result in place in the outer command.
- cp will take a list of files, and as long as the last path is a directory copy them all in there.

Comment: You should consider filenames that contain spaces and other "awkward" characters

Comment: Such evilness as files with spaces in their names!! How dare you bring that up LOL :)

Comment: the pet "nasty" around here is `\n` characters in filenames (perfectly legal; perfectly irritating). I tend to go for the pragmatic approach and ensure code will work with spaces but (only) try to ensure it works with `\n` characters.

Comment: ROFL LOVE IT! :) Never seen that before :)

Comment: `touch $'hello\nworld'`

Comment: I will do no such horrible thing... :) ok I did and it does work.. Someone  should be flogged for this!! LOL.

Answer (score 4):

Do `man xargs` and look at the `-I` flag.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec grep -il "your pattern" {} \; | xargs -I % cp % /dest/dir/
```

To save typing put this command in shell script :

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh 
# Script name: locate
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec grep -il "$1" {} \; | xargs -I % cp % /dest/dir/
```

To run type `locate searchstring` where `searchstring` is the text you are searching for.

Comment: @don_crissti Doesn't make sense, thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer